# Calculate new forecast values with new initial values with Ensemble Kalman Filter

Tags: r, matrix, vector, kalman-filter

I'm using the Ensemble Kalman Filter in Rstudio to look at the Sir model. I have forecast values ​​(xf) ^ i for i = 100 ensemble members and measurements (z) for I. I now want to combine these in the following way:

- For time step 1 to 10 I want to use the forecast values.
- At t = 10 I then make an analysis value: ((xa) ^ i = (xf) ^ i + k (z - M * (xf) ^ i + v ^ i), where k is the weight matrix and v ^ i = a random measurement error, I enter this (xa) ^ i at t = 10.
- Now I want to use these t=10 values ​​as new initial values ​​to calculate the forecast values ​​for t = 11 tm t = 20. For t = 20 the same thing happens as for t = 10.

However, calculating the forecast values in the same way, but with new initial values does not seem to work. My codes are below. Does anybody know how to do this? Thanks!

```
#kalman gain vaste waarden 
#matrix M, 1 bij variabele die we bekijken
#aangeven welke digit 1 moet worden M[,i]=1, S: i=1, I: i=2, R: i=3
M <- matrix(data=0, nrow=1, ncol=3)
M[,2] = 1
zvec <- as.vector(read_excel("z.xlsx", range = "B1:B101")) 
z <- t(zvec)
Rv = z/20 #is variantie van de vi trekking, var = sd^2
vi <- rnorm(n=1001, mean=0, sd = Rv) 
tijdstap <- seq(0, 999, stap) #aangeven om de hoeveel t's er een meting
xfmat <- matrix(0, 3, 100) #voor losse t xfS, xfI en xfR samenvoegen tot forecast matrix
xkl <- list()
xa <- list()

xfS <- matrix(0, 1000, 100)
xfI <- matrix(0, 1000, 100)
xfR <- matrix(0, 1000, 100)
for(u in 1:10){
  xfS[u,] = SS[u,]
  xfI[u,] = II[u,]
  xfR[u,] = RR[u,]
}

for(t in 10:999){
  if(t %in% tijdstap){
    xfmat[1,] = xfS[t,]
    xfmat[2,] = xfI[t,]
    xfmat[3,] = xfR[t,]
    
    k = (covarmatrix[[t]] %*% t(M)) %*% (1/(M %*% covarmatrix[[t]] %*% t(M) + Rv[t/10]))
    xa[[t]] = xfmat + k%*%(z - M%*%xfmat + vi[t/10]) 
    xfS[t,] = xa[[t]][1,] 
    xfI[t,] = xa[[t]][2,]
    xfR[t,] = xa[[t]][3,]
    
    #using xa as new initial values for xf --> this doesn't seem to work
    for(i in 1:100){
      xkl[[i]] <- xkfun(xa[[t]][1,i], xa[[t]][2,i], xa[[t]][3,i], rnorm(1, mean = 1, sd = 0.5), 0.1, )
      xfS[(t+1):(t+10),i] = xkl[[i]][,1]
      xfI[(t+1):(t+10),i] = xkl[[i]][,2]
      xfR[(t+1):(t+10),i] = xkl[[i]][,3]
    }
    
    #new mean and covariance matrix for new values
    gemnew <- gemfun(xfS[(1:(t+10)),], xfR[(1:(t+10)),], xfR[(1:(t+10)),])
    gemnew <- gemfun(xfS, xfI, xfR)
    covarmatrix <- covarmatfun(xfS, xfI, xfR, gemnew, (t+10))
  }
}
```